# Adjust the vertical position of the figures

Tags: margins, tufte

I am writing a book for my calculus course using the Tufte document class.  I have successfully uploaded margin figures into my document in a "marginfigure environment"; however, they are all "bunched up" -- I want to adjust the vertical position of the figures.  How do I adjusts the vertical position of figures in the Tufte document class and in the "marginfigure environment"?  I am new to LaTex; so, if you can, make sure your answers as user friendly as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The marginfigure and margintable environments accept an optional parameter `offset` that adjusts the vertical position of the figure
>   or table. See the “Sidenotes” section above for examples. The specifications are:
>
> ```
> \begin{marginfigure}[offset]
> ...
> \end{marginfigure}
> ```

You should use that (with a length as offset, negative for shifting up).

Comment: For for example, \begin{marginfigure}[10mm]
    \includegraphics{Continuity(2).png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{marginfigure}

Comment: Is this what you are referring too?

Comment: @JoshuaJones Yes, that's it. If that does not work then please post a minimal, *compilable*, code example (MWE) as an edit to your question.

Comment: Hello!  One more question.  How do I adjust the vertical position of a footnote?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @JoshuaJones Use `\sidenote[][offset]{Text}`. But please read the documentation. That really describes all those methods in detail!